# Unity GLTF exporter - material/textures not embedding properly(?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m running some tests with the GLTF exporter package. There seems to be an issue with the exporter or my understanding of it.

I’ll drag a simple window or door object into the scene, and when I export it, instead of a door/window appearing with appropriate materials, it appears all white.

I’ve seen some similar issues happening with FBX exporter where remapping the materials will fix the issue. I was wondering if the same is true for GLTF? Or is there another way to tackle this issue?

Before exporting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFI7y.png

After exporting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAmPM.png

```
        public GLTFSceneExporter(Transform[] rootTransforms, ExportOptions options)
    {
        _exportOptions = options;

        var metalGlossChannelSwapShader = Resources.Load("MetalGlossChannelSwap", typeof(Shader)) as Shader;
        _metalGlossChannelSwapMaterial = new Material(metalGlossChannelSwapShader);

        var normalChannelShader = Resources.Load("NormalChannel", typeof(Shader)) as Shader;
        _normalChannelMaterial = new Material(normalChannelShader);

        _rootTransforms = rootTransforms;
        _root = new GLTFRoot
        {
            Accessors = new List<Accessor>(),
            Asset = new Asset
            {
                Version = "2.0"
            },
            Buffers = new List<GLTFBuffer>(),
            BufferViews = new List<BufferView>(),
            Cameras = new List<GLTFCamera>(),
            Images = new List<GLTFImage>(),
            Materials = new List<GLTFMaterial>(),
            Meshes = new List<GLTFMesh>(),
            Nodes = new List<Node>(),
            Samplers = new List<Sampler>(),
            Scenes = new List<GLTFScene>(),
            Textures = new List<GLTFTexture>()
        };

        _imageInfos = new List<ImageInfo>();
        _materials = new List<Material>();
        _textures = new List<Texture>();

        _buffer = new GLTFBuffer();
        _bufferId = new BufferId
        {
            Id = _root.Buffers.Count,
            Root = _root
        };
        _root.Buffers.Add(_buffer);
    }

        private void ExportNormalTexture(Texture2D texture, string outputPath)
    {
        var destRenderTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(texture.width, texture.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);

        Graphics.Blit(texture, destRenderTexture, _normalChannelMaterial);

        var exportTexture = new Texture2D(texture.width, texture.height);
        exportTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, destRenderTexture.width, destRenderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        exportTexture.Apply();

        var finalFilenamePath = ConstructImageFilenamePath(texture, outputPath);
        File.WriteAllBytes(finalFilenamePath, exportTexture.EncodeToPNG());

        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(destRenderTexture);
        if (Application.isEditor)
        {
            GameObject.DestroyImmediate(exportTexture);
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(exportTexture);
        }
    }

    private void ExportTexture(Texture2D texture, string outputPath)
    {
        var destRenderTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(texture.width, texture.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.sRGB);

        Graphics.Blit(texture, destRenderTexture);

        var exportTexture = new Texture2D(texture.width, texture.height);
        exportTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, destRenderTexture.width, destRenderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        exportTexture.Apply();

        var finalFilenamePath = ConstructImageFilenamePath(texture, outputPath);
        File.WriteAllBytes(finalFilenamePath, exportTexture.EncodeToPNG());

        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(destRenderTexture);
        if (Application.isEditor)
        {
            GameObject.DestroyImmediate(exportTexture);
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(exportTexture);
        }
    }


        private MaterialId ExportMaterial(Material materialObj)
    {
        MaterialId id = GetMaterialId(_root, materialObj);

        //if material has already been exported, return the existing id
        if (id != null)
        {
            return id;
        }

        //else create a new GLTF material
        var material = new GLTFMaterial();


        if (ExportNames)
        {
            material.Name = materialObj.name;
        }


        //if the material has the property of cutoff, 
        if (materialObj.HasProperty("_Cutoff"))
        {
            //extract the cutoff value from the material and apply it to the GLTF material
            material.AlphaCutoff = materialObj.GetFloat("_Cutoff");
        }

        switch (materialObj.GetTag("RenderType", false, ""))
        {
            case "TransparentCutout":
                //if the tag is transparentcutout, the GLTF material alphamode is set to AlphaMode.mask, which will have a binary transparency affect
                material.AlphaMode = AlphaMode.MASK;
                material.Name = material.Name + "_C";
                break;
            case "Transparent":
                //if the tag is transparent, the GLTF material alphamode is set to AlphaMode.blend, which will have smooth transparency (allows objects to be see thru)
                material.AlphaMode = AlphaMode.BLEND;
                material.Name = material.Name + "_T";
                break;
            default:
                //if no tags match, default is opaque, which means nothing can be see thru
                material.AlphaMode = AlphaMode.OPAQUE;
                break;
        }

        material.DoubleSided = materialObj.HasProperty("_Cull") &&
            materialObj.GetInt("_Cull") == (float)CullMode.Off;
            
        if (materialObj.HasProperty("_EmissionColor"))
        {
            material.EmissiveFactor = materialObj.GetColor("_EmissionColor").ToNumericsColorRaw();
        }

        if (materialObj.HasProperty("_EmissionMap"))
        {
            var emissionTex = materialObj.GetTexture("_EmissionMap");

            if (emissionTex != null)
            {
                if(emissionTex is Texture2D)
                {
                    material.EmissiveTexture = ExportTextureInfo(emissionTex, TextureMapType.Emission);

                    ExportTextureTransform(material.EmissiveTexture, materialObj, "_EmissionMap");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogErrorFormat("Can't export a {0} emissive texture in material {1}", emissionTex.GetType(), materialObj.name);
                }

            }
        }

        if (materialObj.HasProperty("_BumpMap"))
        {
            var normalTex = materialObj.GetTexture("_BumpMap");

            if (normalTex != null)
            {
                if(normalTex is Texture2D)
                {
                    material.NormalTexture = ExportNormalTextureInfo(normalTex, TextureMapType.Bump, materialObj);
                    ExportTextureTransform(material.NormalTexture, materialObj, "_BumpMap");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogErrorFormat("Can't export a {0} normal texture in material {1}", normalTex.GetType(), materialObj.name);
                }
            }
        }

        if (materialObj.HasProperty("_OcclusionMap"))
        {
            var occTex = materialObj.GetTexture("_OcclusionMap");
            if (occTex != null)
            {
                if(occTex is Texture2D)
                {
                    material.OcclusionTexture = ExportOcclusionTextureInfo(occTex, TextureMapType.Occlusion, materialObj);
                    ExportTextureTransform(material.OcclusionTexture, materialObj, "_OcclusionMap");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogErrorFormat("Can't export a {0} occlusion texture in material {1}", occTex.GetType(), materialObj.name);
                }
            }
        }

        if (IsPBRMetallicRoughness(materialObj))
        {
            material.PbrMetallicRoughness = ExportPBRMetallicRoughness(materialObj);
        }
        else if (IsCommonConstant(materialObj))
        {
            material.CommonConstant = ExportCommonConstant(materialObj);
        }

        _materials.Add(materialObj);

        id = new MaterialId
        {
            Id = _root.Materials.Count,
            Root = _root
        };
        _root.Materials.Add(material);

        return id;
    }
```

Comment: can you provide us with code or more detail of your workflow.?

Comment: Yes, I edited my original post to show the code. But unfortunately the full code is over 2000 lines so I cannot post all of it, so I only posted parts that I believe are relevant. If you see anything please let me know!